# mongodb custom field with other query

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with this structure:

```
{
 _id : <number>,
 param1 : <number>,
 param2 : <number>,
 param3 : <number>,
 .
 .
 .
}
```

I would like to get the documents back which are right for the conditions and contains an extra array parameter with the _id values of those documents which have the same value in "param1" as the actual row has. So I'd a result like this:

```
{
 _id : <number>,
 param1 : <number>,
 param2 : <number>,
 param3 : <number>,
 .
 .
 .
 extraParameter: [{_id: 1}, {_id: 5}, {_id: 7}, {_id: 10} ...]
}
```

I'm not sure if I can do it but hope you can help me find the best solution for this.

Thanks!

Edited:

I have already made the following query for this but the documentation says don't touch the database in the map but I don't know is there an other way or not ... or is there an easier one?:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(row){
  row.nexts = db.collection.find({param1: row.param1}).map(function(nextElement){
     return {_id: nextElement._id};});
  return row;}
)
```

Comment: extraParameter means the values from 'param1', 'param2', etc. Or do you mean matching between documents. Edit please as your question is not that clear

Comment: @Neil I edited...is that clear now what I want to reach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar with aggregation:

```
db.coll.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$param1", extras: {$push: "$_id"}}}])
```

I inserted this:

```
> db.coll.insert({'_id': 1, param1: 'a', b: 'b'})
> db.coll.insert({'_id': 2, param1: 'a', b: 'c'})
> db.coll.insert({'_id': 3, param1: 'a', b: 'd'})
> db.coll.insert({'_id': 4, param1: 'b', b: 'e'})
```

And it results in this.

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "b",
            "extras" : [
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "a",
            "extras" : [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Then you can iterate over each document, and simply look for the value in the array that's _id matches your value of param1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not that I'm looking for. In your code there is a group by param1 which makes only as many result row as different value of param1 has. I want to get back every rows(!) and each of them should be an 'extras' parameter which contains at least the _id parameter of those rows which have the same value of param1 as the actual row has.

Comment: geri, yeah, I don't think you can do what you want in a single pass.  I think you need to generate the extras for a particular value of param1, in a first pass - saving them to a dict. Then in a second pass go through each document, find the appropriate entry in the dict, and update the document with the extras.

Comment: I was not sure if this is possible or not. Thanks for your suggestion.